# Can a dividing cell that skipped DNA replication become cancerous?

Tags: dna, cancer, dna-replication, mitosis

Let's assume that a cell fails to replicate its DNA during the [S Phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_phase) of the cell cycle. Let's also assume that the appropriate [CDKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclin-dependent_kinase) are inactive (perhaps due to mutation or lack of [cyclin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclin) proteins etc.) and the [G2-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2-M_DNA_damage_checkpoint) checkpoint fails.

2 questions:

1. Will the [Spindle Checkpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindle_checkpoint) fail due to not having duplicated DNA, or can mitosis complete and form [aneuploid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneuploidy) daughter cells?
2. More to the point, **if mitosis *can* complete after a cell fails to replicate its DNA (irrespective of the answer to question 1), can the resulting cell (if viable) lead to a [neoplasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoplasm) or cancer?**

My thought is *no* because the odds of having subsequent generations of cells experience similar losses of DNA via mitosis of un-replicated cells would eventually lead to mostly non-viable next-generation cells and the "uncontrolled" division would cease.

- Though, admittedly, this assumption is dependent on the assumption that the original cell has a heritable issue that "disables" the appropriate checkpoints (vs some random fluke event) allowing the uncontrolled cell line to continue duplicating with un-replicated genomes.
- I'm also not sure how ultrafine anaphase bridges (see [Moreno *et al.* 2016](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/39/E5757)) can be informative for this question.

I found a paper ([Deshpande *et al.* 2005](https://www.nature.com/articles/1208618)) that discusses cyclins and cdks in development and cancer, but their paper focuses on the transition from G1 to the S phase and stops short of discussing mitosis of un-replicated cells

---

*Note: this might sound like a homework question, but *I'M* the one writing the assignment! In fact, it's an exam, and I'm trying to cover my bases for the answers I provide for a different cancer-related question to ensure there are not multiple correct answers.*